# Deleting selected rows in datagridview using multiselect

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I don't think this has a duplicate question... but here it goes. I want to delete selected rows in my datagridview. I will select multiple rows in my datagridview while pressing ctrl and clicking the mouse. The problem is when I click the delete button, the only first selected row will be deleted.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub deleteitem()
    Dim result As DialogResult
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete selected item/s?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView2.CurrentRow
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim query As String = "update Items_tbl set itemstatus='UNAVAILABLE' where id=@id"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
            con.Open()

            For Each Parameter As SqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
                If Parameter.Value Is Nothing Then
                    Parameter.Value = DBNull.Value
                End If
            Next

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Item/s deleted.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        con.Close()
        txt_ItemName.Clear()
        txt_CostPrice.Clear()
        txt_MarkupPrice.Clear()
        txt_Price.Clear()
        txt_ItemName.Focus()
        form_AdminMainPage.Uc_FileMaintenance_Admin1.loaditems()
        resetitems()
    End If
```

Comment: Your code is only acting on the current row, not selected rows.  There is a much easier way to do that - if the DGV is bound to a datasource, if the user presses Delete the control will do all the work,  All you have to do is use `myDataAdapter.Update()`

Comment: can you please show me where to place that myDataAdapter.Update() ?? thanks btw

Comment: I dont even know if you are using a persistent adapter but you put it where/when you want to update the DB.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - also MSDN has many good articles on all the many things the DB Provider objects can/will do for you (like remember all the SQL statements).

Comment: ok i'll take a look later. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Dim result As DialogResult
result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete selected item/s?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
    cmd.Connection = con
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView2.SelectedRows
    Dim query As String = "update Items_tbl set itemstatus='UNAVAILABLE' where id=@id"
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
        con.Open()

        For Each Parameter As SqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
            If Parameter.Value Is Nothing Then
                Parameter.Value = DBNull.Value
            End If
        Next
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Item/s deleted.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    con.Close()
    txt_ItemName.Clear()
    txt_CostPrice.Clear()
    txt_MarkupPrice.Clear()
    txt_Price.Clear()
    txt_ItemName.Focus()
    form_AdminMainPage.Uc_FileMaintenance_Admin1.loaditems()
    resetitems()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the rows, and execute the query, changing the parameter per line.  This assumes you have already opened the connection, so its only the command section of the code.

```
 Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()

        Dim param As New SqlParameter()
        param.ParameterName = "@id"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        For Each r As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView2.SelectedRows

            param.Value = r.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next


    End Using
```

Comment: No one "needs" to do that.  If the user presses delete the control will mark the rows as deleted and remove them from View.  Also thats not VB code - trivial to convert but I doubt it is part of the OPs skill set

Comment: @plutonix i converted the code...its trivial...not sure what you mean by no one needs to do that...if you want to delete from the data source...thats how you do it...one commenter mentioned he could possibly have a connected/typed data set...although it was not referenced in the question